# How can I do squence labeling and entities relationships labeling at the same time

Tags: nlp, annotations, data-annotations, brat, doccano

Is there an NLP annotation tool can do **both of them**?
Btw, I can't install Brat， the download page is 404 page.
I have doccane and tagtog but it seems that they can only do one kind of labeling.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend INCEpTION (https://inception-project.github.io/) for the kind of parallel annotation you're looking for.

It's got many features and takes some setting up, but it can handle more complex tasks and I've found it to be more reliable than Doccano for example. Its developers are from the Computer Science Department at TU Darmstadt and it seems well-suited for NLP research.

Answer (score 0):

[LightTag](https://lighttag.io) can[image: Entity and relation annotation in LT], and it's free to use for moderate sized projects.

I happen to have made LightTag and this feature in particular. It's set up so that you can do entities and then drag and drop them onto each other to create a relationship tree. You can express constituency grammars or dependency grammars.